# Parallel read from sql server in spark

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, jdbc

I am using com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver to read data from sql server in a spark job. To increase the performance , need to read data in parallel. Is the Number of connection made by spark job equal to number of cores in spark-submit command ?

Answer (score 1):

The parallelization unit of Apache Spark are the number of partitions and available workers to process them in parallel. Partitions are created in different ways. For distributed data stores they're defined with the storage. For instance, Apache Kafka stores data in topics which are composed of different partitions. Apache Spark takes advantage of that to process data in parallel.

But for RDBMS it's different since they're not distributed (at least the classical ones), i.e. data is stored in a single node and eventually it's replicated. To use Apache Spark partitioning for that case you must define your partitioning column in JDBC options. You can find more details here https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html or here for examples https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-sql/partitioning-rdbms-data-spark-sql-jdbc/read

> Is the Number of connection made by spark job equal to number of cores in spark-submit command ?

Nope, the number of connection will be equal to the number of your partitions.

Comment: But tied to numPartitions